# RealSense R200 Playback error

Tags: realsense

I have recorded an RSSDK file with R200 on my laptop. But when I try to playback the file on my desktop PC, the depth stream displays correctly, however the color stream doesn't display correctly (example shown as below). At the same time, both streams can display correctly on the laptop.

Does any one know what is the problem? How can I solve it?

Thanks.

[snapshot of playback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MrNn.png)

Comment: try recording a new sequence on the laptop , and make sure you have the same version of the sdk & dcm installed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have Intel GPU enabled on your desktop and latest Intel Graphics driver installed for H264 color playback. Alternatively, you can configure your laptop to store uncompressed/LZO compressed color stream (see documentation for details, there are registry keys for that). But it may be problematic for HD resolution depending on your CPU/hard drive speed. Another option is to decompress H264 streams using clip editor tool after recording.

Comment: This is answer from Intel.